# $f:[a, b]\subset \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitzian function and Riemann-Stieltjes integral

Tags: real-analysis, stieltjes-integral

Show that if $f:[a, b]\subset \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a Lipschitzian function, then the Riemann-Stieltjes integral is independent of the choice of $\xi_i $, for all i = 1,2, ..., n.

I started like this, since $f$ is a Lipschitzian function, then

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq c|x-y|, \forall \:x,y \in [a,b]$$

for some $c>0$. Thus,
$$R_{\Gamma}(\Gamma,f,\phi)=\sum_{i=1}^{m} f(\xi_i)(\phi_i - \phi_{i-1})$$ where $\Gamma=\{a=x_0,x_1,...,x_m\}$ is a partition of $[a,b]$ and $\xi_i$ is such that $\xi_i \in [x_{i-1},x_i]$.

But now I do not know how to use Lipschtiz's condition.

Comment: Make another choice of $\xi_i$, maybe call it $\xi_i'$, and then subtract the two sums.

Comment: I arrived at:  subtract of sums is $\leq c |\xi - \xi'| |\phi(x_i)-\phi(x_{i-1})|$. What can I conclude from this?

Comment: So if $R^1$ and $R^2$ represent different ways of picking $\xi_i$, then $$|R^1(\Gamma, f, \phi) - R^2(\Gamma, f,\phi)| = |\sum_{i=1}^m (f(\xi_i) - f(\xi'_i)) (\phi_i - \phi_{i-1}| \leq c\sum_{i=1}^m |\xi_i - \xi_i'||\phi_i - \phi_{i-1}
|.$$ If we assume that $\phi$ is of bounded variation and that the mesh size of $\Gamma = \delta$, then $$|R^1(\Gamma, f, \phi) - R^2(\Gamma, f,\phi)|  \leq c\cdot \delta\cdot \mathrm{Var}(\phi).$$ What happens when $\delta\to 0$? What does this imply about $R^1$ and $R^2$?

Comment: We can conclude that $R^1$ and $R^2$ are equal. Correct?

Comment: Yes, although it might be more correct to say that $\lim_{|\Gamma|\to 0} |R^1(\Gamma, f, \phi) - R^2(\Gamma,f\phi)| =0$ (here $|\Gamma|$ represents mesh size). So if one choice of $\xi_i$ yields a value for the limit $\lim_{|\Gamma|\to 0} R(\Gamma, f, \phi)$, then any choice of $\xi_i$ will lead to a value for this limit and these values will be equal.

Comment: I understand, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome :)